# Subtract two dates in Java

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

I know this might be a duplicate thread. But I am trying to figure out a way to compute the difference between two dates. From jquery the date string is in the format `'yyyy-mm-dd'`. I read this as a String and converted to java Date like this

```
Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.getParameter(date1));
Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.getParameter(date2));
```

I want to compute the difference in the number of days between these two dates.

**Note:** I cannot use third party API's as those need to reviewed.

Comment: you sure it is mm instead of MM ?

Comment: Which difference? Depending on the locality etc. there are multiple definitions. Take a look at the various 3rd party time API's to see where I'm heading with this comment.

Comment: If you think it is a dup, why not search for it? It's not like the other thread cannot be found...

Comment: @owlstead I cannot use third party apps because it needs to be reviewed by legal team to get it approved. So I have to tinker with what is available in util package.

Comment: @owlstead. Shouldn't the difference in number of days which OP needs be same in all cases?

Comment: @Jimmy: sorry, its `M` yyyy-M-dd

Comment: @user525146 You should add your constraints to the question by editing it. It appears that the most commonly recommended solution is to use third party tools. If you can't, this should be stated up front.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Sorry, edited the thread !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Edit 2018-05-28**
I have changed the example to use Java 8's Time API:

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("2018-05-26", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("2018-05-28", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
Duration diff = Duration.between(d1.atStartOfDay(), d2.atStartOfDay());
long diffDays = diff.toDays();
```

Comment: This will fail across spring's daylight savings boundary. Example (using your code), `d1 = new Date(112, 3-1, 11, 0, 0, 0)`, `d2 = new Date(112, 3-1, 12, 0, 0, 0)`, results in `0`.

Comment: The answer provides a truncated result. For a rounded result: long diffDays = (diff + 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

Comment: @SteveKuo, I know this was a while ago, but do you have a better solution that doesn't fail for daylight savings?  I'm not trying to be snarky, I am working on a similar issue myself and would prefer to avoid code with obvious flaws.

Comment: This failed for me with exception being: `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds`.

What worked for me was:
`d1.until(d2).getDays()`, where both `d1` and `d2` are created as `LocalDate.of(...)`.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you're constrained to using `Date`, you can do the following:

`Date diff = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());`

Here you're computing the differences in milliseconds since the "epoch", and creating a new Date object at an offset from the epoch.  Like others have said: the answers in the duplicate question are probably better alternatives (if you aren't tied down to `Date`).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: doesn't matter because it helps when you are looking for solutions for yourself... This is the answer i will use for my own issue

Answer (score 7):

```
Date d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.
            getParameter(date1));
Date d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse((String) request.
            getParameter(date2));

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

System.out.println("Difference between  " + d1 + " and "+ d2+" is "
        + (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + " days.");
```

Comment: Will fail across the start of daylight savings boundary. Example, d1=`2012-3-11` and d2=`2012-3-12` results in 0 days.