# Substract two date in java and calculating day diffrence For Day light saving on est

Tags: java

i am beginner in java and i wan't to substract to date in java and i wan't diffrence between to date in days.

so for that i have using below approch to solve this

**long diff = Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());**

**long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);**

But this will fail across spring's daylight savings boundary.

Example
d1 = new Date(112, 3-1, 11, 0, 0, 0), d2 = new Date(112, 3-1, 12, 0, 0, 0), results in 0.

so please help me to solve this problem.
i have also referred [Subtract two dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037654/subtract-two-dates-in-java) but not getting excat answer that i wan't.

thank you.

Comment: @tunaki this is not duplicate question i wan't solution for day light saving time

Comment: There are answers properly taking DST into account, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances/23184523#23184523

Comment: you are giving link that not provide good solution for EST @Tunaki

Comment: so pls understand my problem that not given any good suggestion for est and i beginner in java@Tunaki

Comment: This not Duplicate question no one can provide solution for est and if you able to understand this question as duplicate then provide solution in comment  @Tunaki

Comment: The solution given work for all timezones, including EST. You need to read them properly, and refer to the documentation.