# Subtract last modified date to current date

Tags: java

I want to subtract the last modified date of a file to the current date.
Is there a proper way that I can use in java? My problem is I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you bothered to Google this?

Comment: Did you do anything yourself? Like: trying?

Comment: Java Date/Time tutorial - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: I,m trying to subtract LastModifiedDate which is a string to a Date object which is Date dateobj = new Date(); what can i do to subtract a string to a Long value?

Comment: Problem Solve. I follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037654/subtract-two-dates-in-java
thanks for the help guys...

Comment: @tnw The original purpose of Stack Overflow was to be the top results in a Google search. So googling other domains is *not* a requirement to using Stack Overflow. But searching for duplicates *within* Stack Overflow is expected, and posting without bothering to search first certainly is rude.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("c:\\logfile.log");
System.out.println("Before Format : " + file.lastModified());
```

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-file-last-modified-date-in-java/